# How to Remove the first step of registration from the flow of checkout process in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkout, spree

I want to remove the registration step from the checkout process.
I have searched on net and got some clue but I didn't get, what exactly I need to do.
:

In spree guides on github I have read this...

Default Checkout Steps

The Spree checkout process consists of the following steps (With the exception of the Registration step, each of these steps corresponds to a state of the Spree::Order object):

**Registration (Optional – only if using spree_auth_devise extension, can be toggled through configuration setting)**

Address Information

Delivery Options (Shipping Method)

Payment

Confirmation

How do change this, please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it.

We can skip it with just change in **app/config/initializers/spree.rb**

```
Spree::Auth::Config[:registration_step] = false
```

Comment: Easiest way to do this without (IMO) potentially messing up existing order accounts. Thanks!

Comment: Any way to do this via the `Spree.config` block?

Comment: `Spree::Auth.config do |config| config.registration_step = false; end`

Answer (score 1):

you asked that "I want to remove the registration step from the checkout process"

So just remove "spree_auth_devise" gem from your Gemfile, and run bundle install.
there will be no registration step now before checkout-process.

Comment: no, bcoz I am using it for other purpose too. I found the solution already.

Comment: @rathore Any tips for those that follow on how you solved your problem. Accept and close :)